# JavaFX 11 ChoiceBox causes lag

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Im out of ideas. Im trying to create a list with strings. Those strings have a button to remove them from the list. Below the list is a choicebox with the available values.
So when selecting a value from the choicebox, i create a new listitem and remove the value from the dropdown.
I discovered that modifying the children of the choicebox causes a short delay. Not very long but very annoying.

Maybe you know a better way of implementing this or have a fix for the problem. So here's my code

```
default VBox newMultiSelectStringEditor(ListProperty<String> property, String caption, ObservableList<String> values) {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    Label label = new Label(caption);

    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();

    VBox innerVBox = new VBox();
    innerVBox.setSpacing(5.0);
    innerVBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));


    for (String string : property.getValue()) {
        MultiSelectStringOption option = new MultiSelectStringOption(string);
        option.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            innerVBox.getChildren().remove(option);
            property.get().remove(string);
        });
        innerVBox.getChildren().add(option);
    }

    choiceBox.setItems(values);

    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String string) {
            if(string != null && !string.equals("")) {
                choiceBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                MultiSelectStringOption option = new MultiSelectStringOption(string);
                option.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                    innerVBox.getChildren().remove(option);
                    property.get().remove(string);
                });
                property.get().add(string);
                choiceBox.getItems().remove(string);
                innerVBox.getChildren().add(option);
            }
        }
    });



    choiceBox.setMinWidth(680.0);
    choiceBox.setPrefWidth(680.0);


    vBox.getChildren().addAll(label, innerVBox, choiceBox);
    return vBox;
}
```

I tried running the remove action on a separate thread. But then i got a concurrent modification exception...

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: you __must not__ change the state of the sender in a listener to that state (or related properties). Most of the time, we get away with it, though ;)

Comment: Also note that a `ChoiceBox` is for choosing/selecting something, not for carrying out actions, which is what you appear to be doing here (though it's honestly hard to tell from this code snippet). If you want drop downs where you are executing actions, you need some kind of menu (e.g. a `MenuButton`).

Comment: James_D that worked fine :D

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).